# WordPress rewrite occurs after custom rewrite on server (how to change order)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

*We recently made a server switch and are hosting the rewrites on the server instead of in an .htaccess file. I was given this htaconf.txt printout of the rewrite rules on the server.  I attempted to fix the rewrites twice, but it did not fix the issue.  I believe the only two rewrites that are important are the WordPress rewrites on line 4 and the team.php rewrites where I put many pound signs to help it stand out.*

*The guys at the new hosting also put NGINX on the server - I'm not sure if that would do anything to change the rewrites rules, but I'm not sure what it can be at this point.  Any help, hints, or suggestions would be appreciated.*

*I'm sorry that the file is so long, but I'm not sure which parts of the file can be contributing to the error - I assume it's only first half of the code, but I put the other code on there just to make sure I'm not missing anything.*

**/var/www/domain.com/ajax/.htaccess**

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.com/ajax>
    # AddHandler php5-script .php

    # BEGIN WordPress
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault A0
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 7

    <FilesMatch "\.(inc|class)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
    php_value post_max_size 20M
    php_value max_execution_time 200
    php_value max_input_time 200

    #php_value session.save_path /mnt/target02/344586/385371/www.domain.com/web/sessions/
    php_value session.cache_expire 10800
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10800
    php_value session.gc_probability 1000
    php_value session.gc_divisor 100 
    #php_value upload_tmp_dir /mnt/target02/344586/385371/www.domain.com/web/tmp/
    #php_value session.save_path /mnt/target02/344586/385371/www.domain.com/web/sessions/


    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www.domain.com)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sport=(.*)&conference=(.*)&school=(.*)&player=(.*)$
        RewriteRule ^player-profile-new\.php$ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^search(/(.*))?$ /search-results?q=$2 [NC,L]
        #RewriteRule ^birthdays(/(.*))?$ /birthdays.php?by=$2 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*/)?((p)[0-9]+)/edit/deleteimage/([0-9]+)(/)?$ /player-profile?formmode=edit&sport=$1&conference=$4&school=$5&player=$7&deleteimage=1&imageid=$9 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*/)?((p)[0-9]+)/(edit)(/)?$ /player-profile?formmode=edit&sport=$1&conference=$4&school=$5&player=$7 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*/)?((p)[0-9]+)(/)?$ /player-profile?formmode=view&sport=$1&conference=$4&school=$5&player=$7 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/([^/]*)(/)?)?$ /team?sport=$1&conference=$4&school=$5&sort=$7 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^directory/((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/([^/]*)(/)?)?$ /seoteam?sport=$1&conference=$4&school=$5&sort=$7&seo=yes [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /team?sport=$1&conference=$4&school=$5 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))(/)?$ /directory?sport=$1 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^directory/((foot|basket)(ball))(/)?$ /fulldirectory.php?sport=$1&seo=yes [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^players/([^/]*)$ /player-profile.php?player=$1 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^images/playerphotos/([^/]*)/([^/]*).jpg$ /playerphoto.php?player=$2&size=$1 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^images/interviewphotos/([^/]*)/([^/]*).jpg$ /interviewphoto.php?interview=$2&size=$1 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^images/captcha(.)(.)([0-9]{3}).jpg /validate.php?char=$1&type=$2&cachebuster=$3 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^featured-interview/((p)[0-9]*)$ /featured-interview.php?playerid=$1 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^playerpictures$ /imageviewer.php?id=181&playerid=8357&height=480&width=370&ajaxgallery=true [NC,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

**/var/www/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/.htaccess**

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^([a-z]=.*)  index.php?$1  [L,NE]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

**/var/www/domain.com/wp-content/w3tc/pgcache/.htaccess:**

```
<Directory  /var/www/domain.com/wp-content/w3tc/pgcache>
    # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddType text/html .gzip
        AddEncoding gzip .gzip
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.gzip$ no-gzip
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set X-Pingback "http://www.domain.com/xmlrpc.php"
        Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.3"
        Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding, Cookie"
    </IfModule>
    # END W3TC Page Cache
</Directory>
```

**/var/www/domain.com/wp-content/w3tc/min/.htaccess:**

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.com/wp-content/w3tc/min>
    # BEGIN W3TC Minify
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip .gzip
        <Files *.css.gzip>
            ForceType text/css
        </Files>
        <Files *.js.gzip>
            ForceType application/x-javascript
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.gzip$ no-gzip
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.3"
        Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /wp-content/w3tc/min/
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
        RewriteRule .* - [E=APPEND_EXT:.gzip]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%{ENV:APPEND_EXT} -f
        RewriteRule (.*) $1%{ENV:APPEND_EXT} [L]
        RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9]+)\/(.+)\.(include(\-(footer|body))?(-nb)?)\.[0-9]+\.(css|js)$ index.php?tt=$1&gg=$2&g=$3&t=$7 [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END W3TC Minify
</Directory>
```

**/var/www/domain.com/.htaccess**

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.com>
    AddHandler php5-script .php

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault A0
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 7

    <FilesMatch "\.(inc|class)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    php_value session.cache_expire 10800
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10800
    php_value session.gc_probability 1000
    php_value session.gc_divisor 100 

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www.domain.com)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sport=(.*)&conference=(.*)&school=(.*)&player=(.*)$
        RewriteRule ^player-profile-new\.php$ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-photos-([^/]*)-((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)?-((p)[0-9]+)(/)?$ /playerimage.php?images=yes&sport=$3&conference=$6&school=$2&player=$7 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)(/)?$ store-$1 [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule ^store-([^/]*)(/)?$ /oneproduct.php?productid=$1&oneproduct=true [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^schedule-((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)(/)?$ /schedule.php?sport=$1&school=$4&schedule=true [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^search(/(.*))?$ /search-results?q=$2 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)-([^/]*)-([^/]*)?-((p)[0-9]+)/edit/deleteimage/([0-9]+)(/)?$ /$6-$5-$1-$4-$7/edit/deleteimage/$9 [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)-([^/]*)-([^/]*)?-((p)[0-9]+)/(edit)(/)?$ /$6-$5-$1-$4-$7/edit [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)-([^/]*)-([^/]*)?-((p)[0-9]+)(/)?$ /$6-$5-$1-$4-$7 [R=301,L]

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?((p)[0-9]+)/edit/deleteimage/([0-9]+)(/)?$ /$6-$5-$1-$4-$7/edit/deleteimage/$9 [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?((p)[0-9]+)/(edit)(/)?$ /$6-$5-$1-$4-$7/edit [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?((p)[0-9]+)(/)?$ /$6-$5-$1-$4-$7 [R=301,L]

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*/)?((p)[0-9]+)/edit/deleteimage/([0-9]+)(/)?$ /player-profile?formmode=edit&sport=$1&conference=$4&school=$5&player=$7&deleteimage=1&imageid=$9 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*/)?((p)[0-9]+)/(edit)(/)?$ /player-profile?formmode=edit&sport=$1&conference=$4&school=$5&player=$7 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*/)?((p)[0-9]+)(/)?$ /player-profile?formmode=view&sport=$1&conference=$4&school=$5&player=$7 [R=301,NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)-((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)?-((p)[0-9]+)/edit/deleteimage/([0-9]+)(/)?$ /player-profile?formmode=edit&sport=$3&conference=$6&school=$2&player=$7&deleteimage=1&imageid=$9 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)-((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)?-((p)[0-9]+)/(edit)(/)?$ /player-profile?formmode=edit&sport=$3&conference=$6&school=$2&player=$7 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)-((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)?-((p)[0-9]+)(/)?$ /player-profile?formmode=view&sport=$3&conference=$6&school=$2&player=$7&name=$1 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-((foot|basket)(ball))-schedule(/)?$ /yearschedule.php?sport=$3&school=$1&year=$2&schedule=true [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^directory/((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/([^/]*)(/)?)?$ /$5-$1-$4-directory/$7 [R=301,NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)-directory(/)?$ /seoteam?sport=$2&conference=$5&school=$1&sort=$7&seo=yes [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /$5-$1-$4/ [R=301,NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)/$ /team?sport=$2&conference=$5&school=$1 [NC,L]

        # --
        # where the error is occurring - this rewrites happens before the wordpress rewrites and we want the wordpress rewrites to happen first.  
        # --

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/([^/]*)(/)?)?$ /$5-$1-$4/$7/ [R=301,NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-((foot|basket)(ball))-([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /team?sport=$2&conference=$5&school=$1&sort=$6 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /team?sport=$1&conference=$4&school=$5 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^((foot|basket)(ball))(/)?$ /directory?sport=$1 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^directory/((foot|basket)(ball))(/)?$ /directory-$1 [R=301,NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^directory-((foot|basket)(ball))(/)?$ /fulldirectory.php?sport=$1&seo=yes [NC,L]
        # Add Derick Schaefer 5/4/11
        RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-((foot|(?:[^-]*-)?basket)(ball))-schedule/?$ /yearschedule.php?sport=$3&school=$1&year=$2&schedule=true [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-((foot|(?:[^-]*-)?basket)(ball))-schedule/?$ /yearschedule.php?sport=$4&school=$1&year=$3&schedule=true [NC,L]
        # end Derick Schaefer

        RewriteRule ^players/([^/]*)$ /player-profile.php?player=$1 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^images/playerphotos/([^/]*)/([^/]*).jpg$ /playerphoto.php?player=$2&size=$1 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^images/interviewphotos/([^/]*)/([^/]*).jpg$ /interviewphoto.php?interview=$2&size=$1 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^images/captcha(.)(.)([0-9]{3}).jpg /validate.php?char=$1&type=$2&cachebuster=$3 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^featured-interview/((p)[0-9]*)$ /featured-interview.php?playerid=$1 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^playerpictures/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /playerpictures.php?playername=$1&id=$2&playerid=$3&ajaxgallery=true&isimage=true [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^links-(.*)/$ /links.php?linkcategoryname=$1 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^teamstore/(.*)/?$ teamstore-$1 [R=301,L]                        
        RewriteRule ^teamstore-([^/]*)-([^/]*)/$ /teamproduct.php?teamproduct=$1&products=true&teammascot=$2 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^teamstore-([^/]*)/$ /teamproduct.php?teamproduct=$1&products=true [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)-store/?$ /teamproductcategory?teamproduct=$1&category=$2 [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^schedules(/)?$ /scheduledirectory.php?scheduledirectory=1 [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^college-merchandise/?$ /merchandisedirectory.php?collegemerchandise=true [NC,L]
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon

        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-js
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/ecmascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/ecmascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vbscript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/fluffscript

        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template
    </IfModule>

    # BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
            BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
            BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
            BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
            BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
        </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon
    </IfModule>
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
        FileETag None
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
             Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.3"
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$">
        FileETag None
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
             Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.3"
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$">
        FileETag None
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
             Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.3"
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
    # END W3TC Browser Cache

    # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (2\.0\ mmp|240x320|alcatel|amoi|asus|au\-mic|audiovox|avantgo|benq|bird|blackberry|blazer|cdm|cellphone|danger|ddipocket|docomo|dopod|elaine/3\.0|ericsson|eudoraweb|fly|haier|hiptop|hp\.ipaq|htc|huawei|i\-mobile|iemobile|j\-phone|kddi|konka|kwc|kyocera/wx310k|lenovo|lg|lg/u990|lge\ vx|midp|midp\-2\.0|mmef20|mmp|mobilephone|mot\-v|motorola|netfront|newgen|newt|nintendo\ ds|nintendo\ wii|nitro|nokia|novarra|o2|openweb|opera\ mobi|opera\.mobi|palm|panasonic|pantech|pdxgw|pg|philips|phone|playstation\ portable|portalmmm|ppc|proxinet|psp|pt|qtek|sagem|samsung|sanyo|sch|sec|sendo|sgh|sharp|sharp\-tq\-gx10|small|smartphone|softbank|sonyericsson|sph|symbian|symbian\ os|symbianos|toshiba|treo|ts21i\-10|up\.browser|up\.link|uts|vertu|vodafone|wap|willcome|windows\ ce|windows\.ce|winwap|xda|zte) [NC]
        RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_UA:_low]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (acer\ s100|android|archos5|blackberry9500|blackberry9530|blackberry9550|cupcake|docomo\ ht\-03a|dream|htc\ hero|htc\ magic|htc_dream|htc_magic|incognito|ipad|iphone|ipod|lg\-gw620|liquid\ build|maemo|mot\-mb200|mot\-mb300|nexus\ one|opera\ mini|samsung\-s8000|series60.*webkit|series60/5\.0|sonyericssone10|sonyericssonu20|sonyericssonx10|t\-mobile\ mytouch\ 3g|t\-mobile\ opal|tattoo|webmate|webos) [NC]
        RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_UA:_high]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
        RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
        RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
        RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:.gzip]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/wp-admin\/|\/xmlrpc.php|\/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail)\.php|wp-.*\.php|index\.php) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (wp\-comments\-popup\.php|wp\-links\-opml\.php|wp\-locations\.php) [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|wordpress_\[a\-f0\-9\]\+|wordpress_logged_in) [NC]
        RewriteCond "/var/www/domain.com/wp-content/w3tc/pgcache/$1/_index%{ENV:W3TC_UA}%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
        RewriteRule (.*) "/wp-content/w3tc/pgcache/$1/_index%{ENV:W3TC_UA}%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END W3TC Page Cache

    # BEGIN WordPress
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nginx as your webserver, it doesn't use .htaccess files.  .htaccess is (more or less) Apache-specific.  From the nginx docs: http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache-htaccess

See also: [nginx support for .htaccess / rewrite rules? Differences from Apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/24243/nginx-support-for-htaccess-rewrite-rules-differences-from-apache)

If you're, in fact, using Apache, you need to make sure there's a "RewriteEngine On" before any RewriteCond/RewriteRule statements.  The RewriteEngine On seems to be too low in the first file you listed (/var/www/domain.com/ajax/.htaccess).